# Stopping links inside of a table from marking table row as selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've ran into a minor annoyance with a webpage that I am building where by clicking on a link within a table cell is triggering the row to be marked as clicked.

I do however want the rest of that specific cell from being allowed to be clicked.

You can checkout the jsfiddle via: https://jsfiddle.net/r00ftuo1/

Notes:

- Usually my jquery code will save the selected row to a database so on returning the page it would restore the selected row.
- Usually the link will redirect to a different page; it would **NOT** go to `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/r00ftuo1/4/

I think this is what you are looking for.  Also if you need support IE9 or earlier you need to also do the cancelBubbling to stop the event from bubbling up

```
  $("tr").click(function(evt) {
  if ($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
    $(this).removeClass("selected");
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("selected");
  }
});

$("a").click(function(evt){
    evt.stopPropagation();
    window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

Event bubbles out so it starts with the deepest element in the DOM hierarchy and if you *don't* stop the event from propagating it will bubble out to the cell then the row then the table.  So here we need a click handler on the link to stop the event from propagating and you can get the href from the element and navigate using something like this:

```
window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
```

EDIT: forgot the "href"

Comment: Ahh... but i reckon OP's intention was to navigate away from the table to a diff page when user clicks on the link !

Comment: @Luciferous You are correct, each link navigates away from the page, for example one might navigate to google, one might navigate to bing and one might navigate to yahoo.

Comment: @Ryflex There you go that should navigate you to the URL specified on the link.  I forgot the "href" on window.location.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to assign event handler to the table rather that individual rows or cells this is because each event binding counts towards memory not significant for small number of rows but really matter if rows are in hundreds

```
$("table").on("click", "td", function(e){
    if($(e.target).is(':not(a)')){
      $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("selected");
    }
});
```

Comment: Anyway to benchmark your memory theory for say 1 table with 50 headers  (sections) all with 25 rows so that i can compare each method that has been posted as all four posts work correctly just can't see what one is "best"

Comment: this is good point.  Essentially this is a trade off of readability for performance.  If your table has several hundred rows this solution will out perform wiring up a click event to every anchor element as I have suggested.  My solution will end up being more "readable" since it is a direct action on the anchor element but is no where near as scalable as this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is my super lazy hacks solution;

```
$("tr").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName !== "A") {
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    }
}
```

So the class toggles only if the user clicked somewhere in the td - but not on an `A` element.

I also simplified your class setting to use toggle to save a few lines of code.

Here is an updated version of your jsfiddle using this solution https://jsfiddle.net/r00ftuo1/2/

Comment: Yeah, I left them as add/remove because each part does something different so toggle doesn't really apply to this situation.

Comment: Fair enough. I think my answer still tells you how you can do what you want to do though.

Answer (score 1):

So as i understand , you want to make a distinction between the click event on the anchor tags and the click event taking place on the table cell.

Your best bet would be to use **event.target** and write a little bit of logic as per your requirements . A quick code snippet.

```
$("tr").click(function(event) {
  if (event.target == this) { /** your logic **/ } 
 });
```

i hope that answers the question. Further reading. [event.target vs event.currentTarget in jquery](http://joequery.me/code/event-target-vs-event-currenttarget-30-seconds/)

Comment: This has the side effect of not being able to click on spans inside the table for example.

Comment: Well ,i didnt see any spans in the fiddle , so  i kinda just put this together. .But if OP does have a span later on, he would dig around and have his 'Aahaa...' moment on learning about the tagName and/or seeing your answer below ! :)

Comment: Funny enough, I do actually have spans around the links so I assume yours is what I would need. For example: `<td class="hover"><span><a href="#">Alfreds Futterkiste</a></span></td>` I didn't include them in the example because I didn't think it was necessary.

Comment: see my answer below you can click on the link, row and table only down side is you lose default link behavior